# Why do i get "Invalid version" with Spring and ActiveMQ?

Tags: spring, tomcat, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have been using ActiveMQ for a long while. Since I communicate between webapps in my Tomcat server I define some queues in Tomcat's `conf` and have all the libs in `tomcat/lib`, but my apps use Spring and more specifically, spring-jms and activemq-spring libraries.

If I put the `activemq-all-5.11.1.jar` in the `lib` then everything works, but if i just put in individual jars (broker, client, console, kahadb, protobuf and spring), I get the following error:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Invalid version: 6, could not load org.apache.activemq.openwire.v6.MarshallerFactory
  at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36) ~[activemq-client-5.11.1.jar:5.11.1]
  at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:319) ~[activemq-client-5.11.1.jar:5.11.1]
  at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:332) ~[activemq-client-5.11.1.jar:5.11.1]
  at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:305) ~[activemq-client-5.11.1.jar:5.11.1]
  at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:245) ~[activemq-client-5.11.1.jar:5.11.1]
  at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:365) ~[spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
```

I checked the "v6.MarshallerFactory" class and it seems it's related to talking to old versions of brokers. But my broker is running inside Tomcat, and the only ActiveMQ jars I have are those in the Tomcat lib, so I don't understand why someone thinks there's need to talk to an old version of a broker.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the legacy OpenWire module in order to support talking with older broker versions, if you include [this dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-openwire-legacy) in your project it should work.